# Building a bespoke PDF brochure via web form or CMS

Tags: asp.net, .net, pdf, content-management-system, pdf-generation

I'd like to set up a CMS that allows clients to generate a PDF brochure from a series of text inputs and text areas (rich text editor). Clients would fill out text inputs and then select (via a check box) which contents should appear in the exported PDF. This would then stitch together a PDF brochure containing pages only applicable to the options chosen by the client.

All the content is in a CMS with web pages and pdfs built on the fly as per the client's choices. A change in the content is then reflected immediately in the published docs meaning no redundant, out of date pdfs and the benefit of all the tools within the CMS (workflow, publishing dates, security, etc).

Does anyone know of any tools that do this?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I notice you've tagged your question as .net - does the CMS and/or the PDF generating solution need to be in this language?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a .NET solution.

Comment: Something that can be _called_ from .net, or does it actually have to be _in_ .net? I suggested Jasper, as I don't know of any other F/OSS PDF reporting solution that comes close to it; it's Java, and is best set up on a separate server/vm, but very callable from any system (via SOAP).

Answer (score 0):

well your question require a lot of work to be done. I had similar requirement and what i have  done i can brief here. I created multiple views which lets me select their columns and i have used my own rules for differentiating columns from test like {view.columnname}. when your save all information i have used itextsharp for pdf generation.

There is plenty of information on itextsharp.

Comment: Cool, I'll give it a shot. While researching I came across these ones as well:

http://www.realobjects.com/
http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm
http://www.abcpdfeditor.com/
http://www.html-to-pdf.net/
http://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/products.htm
http://www.duodimension.com/html_pdf_asp.net/component_html_pdf.aspx

What do you think of them? Do you know any of them? First one seems to be a good solution, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with design tools and reporting software, plugged into your CMS of choice. For example, you could use Wordpress, and then design your PDF output using iReport, and run it with Jasper. You'd have to work on the bit to translate user inputs to a query passed to the report, but that shouldn't be too much work.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that, regardless of the work you put into the design, when you attempt to share it, it wont look like a brochure at all, only sequential single page PDFs. As an alternative I found a website where you can upload or design your brochure, it can then be downloaded and shared as a flippable, digital brochure. If you are interested check out https://simplebooklet.com/learn/animated-tri-folds.php